# React Navbar pathname doesn't render properly on page change?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

So I'm trying to update my navbar background based on the page I am on, but when I console.log the `window.location.pathname`, it doesn't show the pathname properly.

Here is my function to change the navbar state based on the pathname

```
const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false)

const updateNavbar = () => {
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
        setNavbar(true)
    } else {
        setNavbar(false)
    }

    console.log(window.location.pathname)
}
```

Here's my styled component

```
const Nav = styled.nav`
background: ${({ navbar }) => (navbar ? "red" : "blue")};
```

Then I pass this into my JSX

```
<Nav navbar={navbar}>
{menuData.map((item, index) => (
    <NavLink to={item.link} key={index} onClick={updateNavbar}>
      {item.title}
    </NavLink>
))}
```

The issue is that if I click on my about menu item, in the console it shows

```
/
```

then if I click about again, then it shows

```
/about
```

So when I click `about` it changes the page visually on my screen, but the console logs `/`, so in order for the navbar to change colors, I have to click `about` again, which makes no sense. I pretty much have to click it twice to update the color.

Why doesn't the window.location.pathname automatically update to the page I am on instead of showing the previous link I clicked, then only after I click the link again it shows the correct path?

Also, I am using Gatsby JS and have AOS animations, but I don't think that matters.

Update: If I pass it into a `useEffect` hook, it shows `/` then `/about`, but why doesn't it only show me `/about` instead of showing both the previous and new link I clicked?

```
useEffect(() => {
    updateNavbar()
}, [])
```

Comment: gatsby has router then you should read docs and use it instead of 'external source'

Answer (score 0):

Your console print before your route is rendering!

So you can use:

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(window.location.pathname) }, 3000);
```

to print or get the path after your route change.

Comment: that still doesn't prevent it from rendering twice. It still will say `about` `about` in the console except it's just a 3 sec delay

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that code isn't working because you are setting your `onClick` function at the same time that it navigates to another page. What could work for you could be:

```
const updateNavbar = (destination) => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.pathname !== "/") {
        setNavbar(true)
        navigate("destination")
    } else if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        setNavbar(false)
        navigate("/")
    }

    console.log(window.location.pathname)
}

    <NavLink key={index} onClick={updateNavbar(item.link)}>
      {item.title}
    </NavLink>
```

Basically, you are preventing the code to navigate to your page before it set the state. Changing the native `to` `prop` to `navigate` function.

Another workaround that may work for you is using the state from Gatsby `<Link>` component:

```
<Link
  to={`/your/page`}
  state={{ navbar: true }}
>
```

You can retrieve the value using: `props.location.state.navbar`.

I've added it to give you an approach. On the other hand, the code above will break in the build mode (`gatsby build`) since you are using [`window` (a global object)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) and, since `gatsby build` occurs in the server, where there's no window, it will break the compilation. You should wrap every usage of `window` inside:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  // your stuff
}
```

However, there's a more native approach. Since Gatsby extends from React (and from `@react/router`) it exposes at the top-level component (pages) a [`prop` named `location`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) with all your desired information. Of course, you can pass downside from the page component to any atomized component to use it.

---

After some trials and errors we solved the issue by:

```
const updateNavbar = () => {
  if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
    setNavbar(true)
 } else {
    setNavbar(false)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (window.location.pathname) {
    setNavbar(window.location.pathname)
}

console.log(window.location.pathname)
}, [])

background: ${({ navbar }) => (navbar != "/" ? "#000" : "transparent")};
```

Comment: it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined. also what is navigate in your code?

Comment: Updated. `navigate` is a helper function that internally uses `@reach/router` (aka Gatsby and React) to navigate through pages in the same way that `<Link>` does but with custom events (not clicks). https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function

Comment: what is destination supposed to be? it says error  'destination' is not defined. Also, the console.log isn't showing anything when I click my links

Comment: Of course, it isn't, you have to pass your destination as you did in `to` prop. It should be `item.link`. Check the slash at the beginning of `item.link`.

Comment: it still does the same exact thing as my original function above. also, I can't use item.link because I have a separate button component outside of the data file that also needs to have the state update and change the navbar, so item is undefined for that button. Also, why aren't you using useEffect()?

Comment: What about using the state? I've added a workaround too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224307/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-johnxr).